# Xfce4 and Ubuntu 16.04 and recent firefox: get Emacs key bindings

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, xfce

How can I get Emacs key bindings in firefox (and other applications) when using Xfce4. Several answers relating to `dconf-editor` and `gconf-editor` don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8189 I found the crucial hint: Open `xfce4-settings-editor`, click on `xsettings`, click on `Gtk` and then either change the setting `KeyThemeName` to `Emacs` or create the setting `KeyThemeName` with the `New` button.

Worked for me without restart or logout/login.